# Scrape related pairs of text from multiple <table> tags in an html document

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, domdocument

I have this html source code in database field. I would like to analyze this code, in particular the fields of some tables, and print them on the screen. I cannot publish all the code as it is over 3000 lines of code, this is the start of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="mainLayout">
    <head>
        <title>Anglosphere x3</title>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="content-language" content="en-US" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script data-cmp-ab="1">window.cmp_block_ignoredomains = ['recaptcha.net']</script>
    <script data-cmp-ab="1" src="https://cdn.consentmanager.mgr.consensu.org/delivery/cookieblock.min.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.consentmanager.mgr.consensu.org/delivery/cmp.min.css" />
```

This is the code regarding the tables that interest me:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="troop_details inReturn"
    >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="role">
                                            <a href="/karte.php?d=91628">01] #WorkInProgress</a>
                                    </td>
                <td colspan="11" class="troopHeadline">
                                                                <a href="/karte.php?d=91611">Return from 01-soldier</a>
                                    </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="units">
            <tr>
                <th class="coords">
                                            &#x202d;<span class="coordinates coordinatesWrapper coordinatesAligned coordinatesltr"><span class="coordinateX">(&#x202d;&minus;&#x202d;1&#x202c;&#x202c;</span><span class="coordinatePipe">|</span><span class="coordinateY">&#x202d;&minus;&#x202d;28&#x202c;&#x202c;)</span></span>&#x202c;                                    </th>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u21" title="Phalanx: 1:12:51" alt="Phalanx" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u22" title="Swordsman: 1:25:00" alt="Swordsman" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u23" title="Pathfinder: 0:30:00" alt="Pathfinder" src="/img/x.gif" />                  </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u24" title="Theutates Thunder: 0:26:51" alt="Theutates Thunder" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u25" title="Druidrider: 0:31:53" alt="Druidrider" src="/img/x.gif" />                  </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u26" title="Haeduan: 0:39:14" alt="Haeduan" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u27" title="Ram: 2:07:30" alt="Ram" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u28" title="Trebuchet: 2:50:00" alt="Trebuchet" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u29" title="Chieftain: 1:42:00" alt="Chieftain" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u30" title="Settler: 1:42:00" alt="Settler" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                                    <td class="uniticon last">
                        <img class="unit uhero" title="Hero" alt="Hero" src="/img/x.gif" />                 </td>
                            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody class="units last">
            <tr>
                <th>Troops</th>
                                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit">
                                                    500                                         </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none last">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                            </tr>
        </tbody>

                    <tbody class="infos">
                <tr>
                    <th>Bounty</th>
                    <td colspan="11">
                        <div class="res">
                            <div class="inlineIconList resourceWrapper"><div class="inlineIcon resources" title="Lumber"><i class="r1"></i><span class="value ">6758</span></div><div class="inlineIcon resources" title="Clay"><i class="r2"></i><span class="value ">8093</span></div><div class="inlineIcon resources" title="Iron"><i class="r3"></i><span class="value ">6908</span></div><div class="inlineIcon resources" title="Crop"><i class="r4"></i><span class="value ">15741</span></div></div>                       </div>
                        <div class="carry">
                            <img class="carry full" title="carry"
                                 alt="carry"
                                 src="/img/x.gif"/> &#x202d;&#x202d;37500&#x202c;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&#x202d;37500&#x202c;&#x202c;                     </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        
        <tbody class="infos">
            <tr>
                <th>Arrival</th>
                <td colspan="11">
                    <div class="in">in&nbsp;<span  class="timer" counting="down" value="85">0:01:25</span>&nbsp;hrs.</div>
                    <div class="at"><span>at&nbsp;00:43:10</span><span> </span></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
            <a name="at"></a>
    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="troop_details inReturn"
    >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="role">
                                            <a href="/karte.php?d=91628">01] #WorkInProgress</a>
                                    </td>
                <td colspan="11" class="troopHeadline">
                                                                <a href="/karte.php?d=94829">Return from 0-New Hulk</a>
                                    </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="units">
            <tr>
                <th class="coords">
                                            &#x202d;<span class="coordinates coordinatesWrapper coordinatesAligned coordinatesltr"><span class="coordinateX">(&#x202d;&minus;&#x202d;1&#x202c;&#x202c;</span><span class="coordinatePipe">|</span><span class="coordinateY">&#x202d;&minus;&#x202d;28&#x202c;&#x202c;)</span></span>&#x202c;                                    </th>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u21" title="Phalanx: 0:45:33" alt="Phalanx" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u22" title="Swordsman: 0:53:09" alt="Swordsman" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u23" title="Pathfinder: 0:18:46" alt="Pathfinder" src="/img/x.gif" />                  </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u24" title="Theutates Thunder: 0:16:47" alt="Theutates Thunder" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u25" title="Druidrider: 0:19:56" alt="Druidrider" src="/img/x.gif" />                  </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u26" title="Haeduan: 0:24:32" alt="Haeduan" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u27" title="Ram: 1:19:44" alt="Ram" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u28" title="Trebuchet: 1:46:18" alt="Trebuchet" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u29" title="Chieftain: 1:03:47" alt="Chieftain" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                    <td class="uniticon">
                        <img class="unit u30" title="Settler: 1:03:47" alt="Settler" src="/img/x.gif" />                    </td>
                                                    <td class="uniticon last">
                        <img class="unit uhero" title="Hero" alt="Hero" src="/img/x.gif" />                 </td>
                            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody class="units last">
            <tr>
                <th>Troops</th>
                                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit">
                                                    400                                         </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                                    <td class="unit none last">
                                                    0                                           </td>
                            </tr>
        </tbody>

                    <tbody class="infos">
                <tr>
                    <th>Bounty</th>
                    <td colspan="11">
                        <div class="res">
                            <div class="inlineIconList resourceWrapper"><div class="inlineIcon resources" title="Lumber"><i class="r1"></i><span class="value ">6130</span></div><div class="inlineIcon resources" title="Clay"><i class="r2"></i><span class="value ">5835</span></div><div class="inlineIcon resources" title="Iron"><i class="r3"></i><span class="value ">5638</span></div><div class="inlineIcon resources" title="Crop"><i class="r4"></i><span class="value ">12397</span></div></div>                       </div>
                        <div class="carry">
                            <img class="carry full" title="carry"
                                 alt="carry"
                                 src="/img/x.gif"/> &#x202d;&#x202d;30000&#x202c;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&#x202d;30000&#x202c;&#x202c;                     </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        
        <tbody class="infos">
            <tr>
                <th>Arrival</th>
                <td colspan="11">
                    <div class="in">in&nbsp;<span  class="timer" counting="down" value="920">0:15:20</span>&nbsp;hrs.</div>
                    <div class="at"><span>at&nbsp;00:57:05</span><span> </span></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The data that interest me are the following:

1. Return from 01-soldier **00:43:10**
2. Return from 0-New Hulk **00:57:05**

This is my code, but it gives like output an empty **array ( )**;

```
<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $caserma = $_SESSION["caserma"];
    
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($_SESSION["caserma"]);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $texts = [];
    foreach ($xpath->query("//table[contains(@class, 'troop_details') and contains(@class, 'inReturn')]//td[@class='troopHeadline']//a[@href]/text()") as $textNode) {
        $texts[] = $textNode->nodeValue;
    }        
    var_export($texts);
     ?>
```

I think that my input is no valid xml/html, so I tried looking for errors like this:

```
 $object = simplexml_load_string($_SESSION["caserma"]);

 if ($object === false) {
     $errors = libxml_get_errors();
     print_r($errors)
 }
```

and this is my output:

> Array ( [0] => LibXMLError Object ( [level] => 3 [code] => 4 [column]
> => 1 [message] => Start tag expected, '<' not found [file] => [line] => 1 ) )

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to access the `<div class="at">` text which exists in the same `<table>` as the earlier matched text.

Normally, I just feed the `$table` variable into the nested xpath `query()` calls, but I think you have too much malformed html for that to be reliable (this was my discovery while testing, unless I simply goofed up in my demo).

An alternative technique that ended up working was to get the node path and prepend it to the nested xpath path strings.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37679621/2943403

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y9rHi))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($_SESSION["caserma"]);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$texts = [];
foreach ($xpath->query("//table[contains(@class, 'troop_details') and contains(@class, 'inReturn')]") as $table) {
    $tablePath = $table->getNodePath();
    $texts[] = [
        'troopHeadline' => $xpath->query($tablePath . "//td[@class='troopHeadline']//a[@href]/text()")[0]->nodeValue,
        'atTime' => substr($xpath->query($tablePath . "//div[@class='at']/span[starts-with(text(), 'at')]/text()")[0]->nodeValue, -8)
    ];
}
var_export($texts);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'troopHeadline' => 'Return from 01-soldier',
    'atTime' => '00:43:10',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'troopHeadline' => 'Return from 0-New Hulk',
    'atTime' => '00:57:05',
  ),
)
```

Comment: At first thanks for your time. Nothing my output was always the same, empty array.

Comment: I am using your input to successfully demo.  There must be something off about your data or your implementation of my advice.

Comment: `$caserma = $_SESSION["caserma"];
$_SESSION["caserma"] = <<<HTML
$caserma;
HTML;`
Is this correct?

Comment: Could it be that the problem is in the text contained in the variable? Basically I get the source code through a textarea, put everything in the database and save in the session variable $ _SESSION ["caserma"], in this way probably i have only text and not an object, right?

Comment: That is correct.  If `$_SESSION["caserma"]` contains the text of the html document, you load that string into DOMDocument.  I am only using "HEREDOC" syntax (`<<<SOMETHING ... SOMETHING;`), because I don't have access to your session array.  If the text is already in your session array, then just directly use that value.  Notice that my answer in no way employs `simplexml_load_string`.

Comment: I really don't know, because if I insert the tables that you have put in the demo directly in the code (with the heredoc syntax) everything works fine (and therefore your code is perfect) but if I insert these tables in the textarea and take them by `$_SESSION["caserma"]` this it doesn't work anymore and gives me an empty array.

Comment: I solved it, I don't know why but I solved it. Basically instead of taking the data via `$ SESSION ["caserma"]` I get them directly from the database (`SELECT caserma FROM `etc etc)

Comment: I am glad you found a resolution, but I'll be honest, I can't think of any scenarios where storing an entire html document in the session array will be appropriate.  If you MUST store data in the session, narrow it down to the bare essential parts so that you do not bloat your session variable.  You should debug what is wrong with your session variable -- is that array empty? do you have session_start() at the start of every page load? There are too many ways that this could be breaking so I can't really help any more.

Comment: Yes, you're right, actually it was a completely useless thing, I'm just starting not with programming and so slowly I'm trying to learn, thank you for your time, see you next time.

Comment: We all start somewhere.  Have faith that things will get clearer over time, but also know that programming is a career of lifelong learning.

Comment: yes, sure. Sorry, the last thing, now i have this value when i can click on it (and not simple string), how can i transform this value into simple string? i tried with serialize (), implode (), join () but nothing

Comment: Do you mean `var_export(array_map('implode', $result));`?  How are you using this collection of strings?  Maybe you only want to declare each pair of values as a single string: `$texts[] = $xpath->query($tablePath . "//td[@class='troopHeadline']//a[@href]/text()")[0]->nodeValue . ' ' . substr($xpath->query($tablePath . "//div[@class='at']/span[starts-with(text(), 'at')]/text()")[0]->nodeValue, -8);`?

Comment: I have insert the arrays into a table, but this values are hyperlink. I want only a text. I don't know how to explain. As if I wanted to write `<p> text </p>` where text is my array value.

Comment: Sorry, how i can take the (x,y) coordinates -1 and -28 of this code? `<span class="coordinateX">(&#x202d;&minus;&#x202d;1&#x202c;&#x202c;</span><span class="coordinatePipe">|</span><span class="coordinateY">&#x202d;&minus;&#x202d;28&#x202c;&#x202c;)</span>`